# Applying border-right to all elements except the last one

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I have Wordpress pages looking like this: Page 1 | Page 2 | Page 3 |

I don't want a border-right on Page 3. How can I delete it?

```css
.primary-navigation {
  float: left;
}
.primary-navigation a {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding-left: 23px;
  padding-right: 23px;
  border-right: 1px dotted #7b7f82;
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1;
}
.primary-navigation .menu-item-has-children a {
  padding-right: 35px
}
```

```html
<div id="primary-navigation" class="primary-navigation" role="navigation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
  <nav id="navigation" class="navigation clearfix mobile-menu-wrapper">
    <a href="#" id="pull" class="toggle-mobile-menu">
      <?php _e( 'Menu'); ?>
    </a>
    <?php if (has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu')) { ?>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'theme_location'=>'primary-menu', 'menu_class' => 'menu clearfix', 'menu_id' => 'menu-primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'walker' => new mts_menu_walker)); ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <ul class="menu clearfix" id="menu-primary-menu">
      <?php wp_list_pages( 'title_li='); ?>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `:last-child`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `:last-child` pseudo-class to set `border-right: none;` on the last `<a>` in your `.primary-navigation`.

```
.primary-navigation a {
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    padding-right: 23px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #7b7f82;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1;
}

.primary-navigation li:last-child a {
    border-right: none;
}
```

More on the `:last-child` pseudo-class on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child).

Comment: Well, it made every border disappear

Comment: It should work, unless the `<a>s` aren't direct children of `.primary-navigation`. Could you post your `HTML` code?

Comment: As expected the `<a>s` aren't direct children of `.primary-navigation`. See my updated code.

Answer (score 5):

You can use CSS selector `:not(:last-child)` to select all your element BUT the last.

```css
ul.menu {
  list-style-type : none;
  padding : 0px;
}

ul.menu > li {
  display : inline-block;
  padding-right : 2px;
}

ul.menu > li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right : solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>Page 1</li>
  <li>Page 2</li>
  <li>Page 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this style to you css:

```css
.primary-navigation { float: left; }
.primary-navigation ul {
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    padding-right: 23px;
    border-right: 1px dotted #7b7f82;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1;
}
.primary-navigation ul:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<li class="primary-navigation">
<ul class="menu clearfix" id="menu-primary-menu">Page 1</ul> 
<ul class="menu clearfix" id="menu-primary-menu">Page 2</ul> 
<ul class="menu clearfix" id="menu-primary-menu">Page 3</ul> 
<ul class="menu clearfix" id="menu-primary-menu">Page 4</ul> 
</li>
```

Comment: I tried to use :last-child but it didn't work on Wordpress. I added your code which didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you add your code to try to see why its not working?

Comment: <ul class="menu clearfix" id="menu-primary-menu">
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li='); ?>
</ul>

Comment: @Mehmet I add an example for you you need to use "ul" instead of "a" tag in your class definition

Answer (score 2):

```
.primary-navigation a {
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    padding-right: 23px;
    /* border-right: 1px dotted #7b7f82;   <-- REMOVE from this declaration block */
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1;
}

.primary-navigation a:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: 1px dotted #7b7f82;
}
```

Using the [*:not() negation*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and [*:last-child*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) pseudo-classes, all anchors are given the border, except the last one.

Just FYI, this method may be simpler:

```
a + a {
    border-left: 1px dotted #7b7f82;
}
```

Using the [*adjacent sibling selector*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), a left-side border can be applied to all anchors immediately following another anchor. This means no left-side border on the first anchor, and no right-side border on the last anchor.

Comment: It made all border disappear. Is it because of Wordpress pages?

Comment: You may have other styles overriding these. Try adding `!important` to each rule and see if that works.

Comment: Really dig the `a + a` here. I was here just trying to remember how to `:not(:last-child)` for a borders on table cells (td) in a table, and `td + td { border: 1px solid; }` works and is too smooth not to use!